# Where interceptor is written or is there an central place which is called before every request to all APIs?

Tags: apache-superset

We are customising Superset for a requirement in which we need to send one more extra security token (custom token) from FRONTEND-SUPERSET to BACKEND-SUPERSET but I'm unable to find central place from where all API call pass to backend where I can write my code?

Or

Is there any interceptor which gets called before every API call where I can set extra header in cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Superset uses Flask, so you can use the [`before_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) decorator to create a method that is called before every request. I've used it in the past to log all incoming requests.